# How do we detect thunderbolts in real time?

Tags: meteorology, satellites, thunderstorm

When I look at radar data (in Windy for example), and I'm looking into a thunderstorm, I often see thunderbolts appearing in 'real time' on the map. How does that work ? I assume some satellites have the ability to detect them, but I wonder what is the physical process behind that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_detection